# VBA to SmartSheet API

Tags: json, excel, vba, api, get

```
Public Function GETSHEET(sID As String, xTOK As String) As WebResponse


Dim sSHEET As New WebClient
Dim xD As New Dictionary
Dim xR As WebResponse
Dim xNC As New Collection

sSHEET.BaseUrl = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/"

Set xR = sSHEET.GetJson(sID)
xNC.Add WebHelpers.CreateKeyValue("Authorization", "Bearer " & xTOK)
xD.Add "Headers", Headers
Set xR = sSHEET.GetJson(sID, xD)

If xR.StatusCode = WebStatusCode.Ok Then
    Set GETSHEET = xR
Else
    bR = MsgBox("Error!" & Chr(10) & _
                        "Status Code : " & xR.StatusCode & Chr(10) & _
                        "Code Description : " & xR.StatusDescription & Chr(10) & _
                        "Content : " & xR.Content, vbCritical, "Error!")

    Debug.Print "Error!"
    Debug.Print xR.StatusCode
    Debug.Print xR.StatusDescription
    Debug.Print xR.Content
    End
End If

End Function
```

So, I got response Status code:404 Error code:1006 - not found, but Token is OK and ID of sheet is given within function. Why it isnt finding sheet?

Comment: what additional library are you using that has methods such as .GetJson for one of its members?

Comment: vba-web by TimhallL https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

Comment: Ah yes. Played with that a long time ago.

Comment: @QHarr, so what did I did wrong?

Comment: Have you tried testing with something like Postman? I'm afraid I can't really help on this question as I don't have an account and not really sure what the expected end result would be.

Answer (score 0):

@QHarr, Ive just tried different approach. Much easier actually. Thank you for help!

```
Public Sub IMPORTMESTER()

Dim username As String, APIkey As String
Dim URL As String
Dim httpReq As Object


xTOK = "bdj62bzknriy3dd9g561on2xl2"

URL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/7352150637471620"

Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
With httpReq
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & xTOK
    .send
    MsgBox "Status = " & .statustext & vbNewLine & _
           "Response = " & .responseText
End With

End Sub
```